# scraping tables with rvest in R

Tags: r, rvest

I'm attempting to scrape the table featuring trading data from this website: https://emma.msrb.org/IssuerHomePage/Issuer?id=F5FDC93EE0375953E043151E0A0AA7D0&type=M

This should be a rather simple process, but I run this code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://emma.msrb.org/IssuerHomePage/Issuer?
id=F5FDC93EE0375953E043151E0A0AA7D0&type=M"

deals <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="lvTrades"]') %>%
  html_table()
 deals <- deals[[1]]
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in deals[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

On top of this, it seems the scrape isn't returning any text.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Sorry if this seems a little elementary, I'm relatively new to this scraping stuff.

Comment: The page you are requesting returns a terms and agreement page.

Comment: You are totally right.  Any ideas on how to bypass the initial agreement page and go straight to the URL I'm attempting to access?

Comment: You can try using `rvest::html_session` in combination with `rvest::follow_link` to get to the page you want

Comment: You'll probably have to simulate a browser session (using `html_session`) and accept the terms from within R.

Comment: Right.  You wouldn't happen to have any good sources for learning how to use html_session function of rvest?  Thanks for your help thus far!